# Device not being detected in debugging mode?

Tags: android

I have an iBall Tablet model no. i9702 i have also installed the device drivers for that device.However when i run (my project) Run As->Target->Always prompt to pick device. My device does not show up.Also i have checked the debugging mode in developers option tab.Can some one tell me what may be the reason for it.

Comment: Have you tried to run ./adb devices? Give us more info :

your OS, what development tool are you using, what version of android your device have? What is your project build target?

Comment: I am using windows 7 64 bit.Eclipse and device version is 4.0. and in manifest android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" .